# Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit running 64-bit version of R in W/ Prof 64-bits 8GBRAM

Tags: r

I'trying to run the function`Q_objective` from the package `ROI` but get a C stack error after the following instruction:

```
foo <- Q_objective(Q = CovMat, L = rep(0, ncol(Myarray)))
```

I have tried with a very small array and get the same error so it seems that is nothing to do with memory at all.

I have found the instruction Cstackinfo and get the following but can't understand what's wrong:

> Cstack_info()
>         size    current  direction eval_depth 
>     10485760       8504          1          2

Comment: can you give sample data (or if its too big), the output of `str` and your OS, total ram installed or whether or not your system is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I don't see how to upload the file but it is a standard csv with long data type and 480x480 matrix size. My OS is W7 Professional 64 bit with 8GB RAM and running R 64 bit version. Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet in that case is to check the output of `memory.limits()`. In addition, clear your workspace, and repeat the analysis to check if the cause is a build up of objects in the workspace.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I cleaned my workspace check memory.limit() and memory.size() and got 8107 and 34.91 so it seems is nothing to do with memory. I tried with the 32 bit version of R and get Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion ... have tried changing the options(expressions to a higher figure) but didn't work.