# Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit in Windows environment

Tags: windows, r, stack-overflow, rpy2

I'm doing geostatistical interpolations in R on a 5600 x 5700 matrix and, despite having available memory, I'm getting the error "C stack usage is too close to the limit."

There are a few SO questions related to this issue including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719349/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411509/error-c-stack-usage-is-too-close-to-the-limit-running-64-bit-version-of-r-in-w). These sources and others I've seen online suggest changing the stack size often resolves this issue. Some suggested this change: `R_CStackLimit = (uintptr_t)-1` in the file "Rinterface.h". However I am on Windows 7 (x64), using R 2.15.3 (x64) via the `Rpy2` module (v 2.3.6 x64 by way of [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)) in Python 2.7, and "Rinterface.h" isn't to be found. How can I otherwise change my effective stack limit for R?

The code that I am running for the interpolation is as follows (except I have it wrapped in a function):

```
  d <- read.table(wd,header=TRUE,sep=',')
  d <- na.omit(d)
  coordinates(d) <- ~ longdd+latdd ## convert simple data frame into a spatial data frame object
  proj4string(d) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
  stations <- spTransform(d, CRS(utm19))
  names(stations@data)[1] <- "stations"

  grids <- readGDAL("dem.asc")
  names(grids) <- "dem"
  grids$dsea <- readGDAL("dsea.asc")$band1
  proj4string(grids) <- CRS(utm19)
  ov <- overlay(grids, stations)
  stations$dem = ov$dem
  stations$dsea = ov$dsea

  stations <- stations[!is.na(stations$dsea),]

  vgm <- vgm(model="Sph",range=25000)

  v <- variogram(air_temp_max_c~dem+dsea,stations) 
  vgm_max_r<-fit.variogram(v, model=vgm)
  temp_uk <- krige(air_temp_max_c~dem+dsea, locations=stations, newdata=grids, model=vgm_max_r)
  write.asciigrid(temp_uk[1],outmax)
  max_cv <- krige.cv(air_temp_max_c~dem+dsea, locations=stations, vgm_max_r)

  max_cv <-data.frame(max_cv)
  max_cv["date"] <- dt
  max_cv["gs"] <- gs
  max_cv["parameter"] <- "air_temp_max_c"
  write.table(max_cv,file=<outFile>,sep=",",row.names=F)
```

Comment: There might be something slightly inefficient in your code: it may be easier to fix than to recompile R (especially on Windows). How are you doing those interpolations?

Comment: This value is already the default (   https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/src/2f51ee90bb3fce452d09ebe435efd9ccfc06c1ac/rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c?at=default#cl-1260 ). Which version of rpy2 are you using by the way ? (`import rpy2; print(rpy2.__version__)`)

Comment: @lgautier - does this imply that code optimization is where I should focus for a work around? I've updated my answer to include the rpy2 version: v2.3.6 x64 by way of Christoph Gohlke

Comment: @metasequoia - You could also check with Christoph whether the stack limit is what I think it is on Windows (its setting is conditional in the C code for rpy2). Otherwise, yes. It would mean that the limit would also be hit while running this in R only, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can use #include "Rinterface.h" and put file Rinterface.h in the same file as your C or R code.

The "Rinterface.h" is available at: 
https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/Rinterface.h